# I'm switching to Devise and I'm unable to view my users index page or individual users

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, rolify

I'm switching my UAM to Devise and Rolify and I'm running into a snag viewing my user index and user show pages.

In the rails console, I'm able to view the user's email via `User.first.email` so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error about the Nil class.

I'm able to log in and log out with no issues.

In a few of the SOF posts, I saw that the nil class is pointing to the current user being nil but there is some logic built into the navigation menu around `current_user` so I know that's working as well.

In the screenshot of the Rails error message, it is indicating a params of 1 which should correspond to the user I'm currently logged in with.

Any thoughts? What could I be overlooking?

Here's the full trace:

```
14:55:04 web.1  | Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 38ms (ActiveRecord: 12.7ms | Allocations: 13119)
14:55:04 web.1  |
14:55:04 web.1  |
14:55:04 web.1  |
14:55:04 web.1  | ActionView::Template::Error (undefined method `email' for nil:NilClass):
14:55:04 web.1  |     1: <div class="container">
14:55:04 web.1  |     2:   <h2>Showing User Details</h1>
14:55:04 web.1  |     3:
14:55:04 web.1  |     4:    <%= image_tag avatar_url(@user), class: "img-circle avatar_large" %>
14:55:04 web.1  |     5:
14:55:04 web.1  |     6:   <div>
14:55:04 web.1  |     7:     <%= link_to "Edit your profile", edit_user_path(@user) %>
14:55:04 web.1  |
14:55:04 web.1  | app/helpers/application_helper.rb:3:in `avatar_url'
14:55:04 web.1  | app/views/users/show.html.erb:4
```

[Screenshot of Rails Error Mesage](https://share.cleanshot.com/5DT5jm)

[Screenshot of User Database in PG](https://share.cleanshot.com/vrIKXE)

Here's my user controller:

```
# frozen_string_literal: true

class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
  before_action :require_user, only: %i[edit update]
  before_action :require_same_user, only: %i[edit update destroy]

  def show
    @events = @user.events
    @events = @user.artists
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      flash[:notice] = "Welcome to the site #{@user.username}, you have successfully signed up"
      redirect_to user_path(@user)
    else
      render "new"
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil if @user == current_user
    flash[:notice] = "Account and all associated events successfully deleted"
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  def edit; end

  def update
    if @user.update(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "Your account information was successfully updated"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render "edit"
    end
  end

  private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password)
    end

    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    def require_same_user
      if current_user != @user && !current_user.admin?
        flash[:alert] = "You can only edit or delete your own account"
        redirect_to login_path
      end
    end
end
```

Here's my user model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :events, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :artists, dependent: :destroy
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your **app/views/users/show.html.erb** is looking for a **@user** variable in your **users_controller**, which you havent defined in the corresponding **show** method.

so you either grab the **current_user** or the id from the params:

```rb
def show
  @user = current_user
  # OR
  @user = User.find(params[:id])
end
```

depending on setup and usecase ...

EDIT:
its also worth mentioning that you do have a ***set_user*** method which you arent using: `before_action :set_user, only: %i[show edit update destroy]`

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use `set_user` method.

```rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: %i[show edit update destroy]
end
```

But I recommend using `current_user` in `show` method.

Answer (score 0):

You have a set_user method defined in your controller, this sets the @user variable, however you are not calling that method.

Usually this would be done in a before_action

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :update, :destroy]
...
```